# How toget data with python web scraping that is inside a <ul> and i don't have a class, id or name, and also the xpath never is the same?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

Well, my problem is this. I want to gather data from a web page using python and selenium, here is the html i need to get data from

```
 <div class="order-detail order-price">
      <div>
        <p class="item-left text--semibold">
           Subtotal
        </p>
        <p class="item-right text--semibold">$1420.00</p>
     </div>
  </div>
```

<The data i need is the inner text from the last "p" element, the number. I can use the Xpath for that one specific, but this is inside a ul elemten which has a lot of li elements, inside those li, you have that div code.

The problem is that the Xpath of that div changes in every li because i can have more or less div before that one specific, so i can not use Xpath, i dont have an id, a name and the class name is equal to all other div and my program can not grab one specific. Also, i need to grab one by one so i can have them order because every once in a while i have to gather another specific div and save that data in the same spot.
This is my code so far

```
ul_principal = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/main/div[5]/section/div/div/div/div/ul/li[2]/div/div/div[1]/div[4]/ul[2]')

li_options = ul_principal.find_elements_by_tag_name('li')
for li in li_options:

     driver.implicitly_wait(100)

     li.click()

     div_Subtotal = li.find.element_by_class_name("order=detail order-price")

     if div_Subtotal is not None:
       div_Subtotal.find_element_by_class_name("item-right text--semibold").get_property('innerText')
```

i use li.click() to know if i can travel within the li, this works, but i can not grab the info.
I can not give you the web page because its behind a password and it is private

Answer (score 0):

Try something like `BS4.find(class_ = "order-detail order-price").find("p", {"class": "item-right"}).text`

Answer (score 0):

To extract and print the text **$1420.00** you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `css_selector` and `get_attribute()`:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("ul li div.order-detail.order-price p.item-right.text--semibold").get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- Using `xpath` and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//ul//li//div[@class='order-detail order-price']//p[@class='item-right text--semibold']").text)
  ```

---

Ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR` and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "ul li div.order-detail.order-price p.item-right.text--semibold"))).text)
  ```
- Using `XPATH` and `get_attribute()`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//ul//li//div[@class='order-detail order-price']//p[@class='item-right text--semibold']"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [How to retrieve the text of a WebElement using Selenium - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55240245/how-to-retrieve-the-text-of-a-webelement-using-selenium-python/55241232#55241232)

---

### References

Link to useful documentation:

- [`get_attribute()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute) method `Gets the given attribute or property of the element.`
- [`text`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.text) attribute returns `The text of the element.`
- [Difference between text and innerHTML using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40416048/difference-between-text-and-innerhtml-using-selenium/55902072#55902072)